# Next.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shallow')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to intercept route changing based on `boolean` value(if there are unsaved changes). 
I found the [topic related discussions](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2476) and tried to implement, but it doesn't work properly.
Clicking `Cancel` button throws this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shallow')

 const routeChangeStart = (url: string) => {
  55 |   if (Router.asPath !== url && unsavedChanges && !confirm(message)) {
> 56 |     Router.events.emit('routeChangeError')
     |    ^
  57 |     Router.replace(Router, Router.asPath)
  58 |     throw 'Abort route change. Please ignore this error.'
  59 |   }
```

Furthermore, clicking the `cancel` button it will change the url 1 step back. Let's say my url is `localhost:3000/products/10`, it will become `localhost:3000/products` and throw the error described above.
I'm not sure if it's the best approach, or it's possible only with `next.js router`, I mean without `global window properties`, so any help will be appreciated.
Topic related code snippet below.

```
import Router from 'next/router'
 
.....
////
 const [unsavedChanges, setUnsavedChanges] = useState<boolean>(true)

 const message = 'Do you want to leave?'

  useEffect(() => {
    const routeChangeStart = (url: string) => {
      if (Router.asPath !== url && unsavedChanges && !confirm(message)) {
        Router.events.emit('routeChangeError')
        Router.replace(Router, Router.asPath)
        throw 'Abort route change. Please ignore this error.'
      }
    }

    const beforeunload = (e: any) => {
      if (unsavedChanges) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.returnValue = message
        return message
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeunload)
    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', routeChangeStart)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeunload)
      Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', routeChangeStart)
    }
  }, [unsavedChanges])
```